# Improving PWA Page Load

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a [PWA](https://github.com/claytoncarney/offline-kjv-2), which is essentially a book reader. As a result, it needs lots of data (viz. the book text) to operate. When analyzed by [Lighthouse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk), it scores poorly on the Page Load Check.

My question is: What methods could I employ to improve the page load, while still ensuring offline functionality?

I could have a minimal start page (e.g., just display a 'Please wait, downloading text' message) and then dynamically download (via injected script tag or AJAX) the JSON data file. However, I'm not sure how I would subsequently ensure that the data is fetched from the cache.

Just wondering how others have handled this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has gone tumbleweed, I decided to post the results of my attempts.

Based on [Jake's article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle), I used the following script and Chrome DevTools to study service worker events:

```
'use strict';

let container = null;
let updateFound = false;
let newInstall = false;

window.onload = () => {
  container = document.querySelector('.container');
  let loading = document.createElement('div');
  loading.classList.add('loading');
  loading.innerHTML = 'Downloading application.<br>Please wait...';
  container.appendChild(loading);
  console.log(`window.onload:      ${Date.now()}`);
  swEvents();
};

let swEvents = () => {
  if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
      console.log(`sw.ready:           ${Date.now()}`);
      if (!updateFound) {
        loadApp();
        return;
      }
      newInstall = true;
      console.log(`new install:        ${Date.now()}`);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(`sw.ready error: ${error.message}`);
    });
  }

  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then((reg) => {
    reg.onupdatefound = () => {
      updateFound = true;
      console.log(`reg.updatefound:    ${Date.now()}`);
      const newWorker = reg.installing;
      newWorker.onstatechange = (event) => {
        if (event.target.state === 'activated') {
          console.log(`nw.activated:       ${Date.now()}`);
          if (newInstall) {
            loadApp();
            return;
          }
          refresh();
        }
      };
    };
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(`reg.error: ${error.message}`);
  });
};

let refresh = () => {
  console.log(`refresh():          ${Date.now()}`);
  // window.location.reload(true);
};

let loadApp = () => {
  console.log(`loadApp():          ${Date.now()}`);
  let child;
  while (child = container.firstChild) {
    container.removeChild(child);
  }
  let message = document.createComment('p');
  message.textContent = 'Application loading';
  container.appendChild(message);
  let tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = './app.js';
  document.body.appendChild(tag);
};
```

Along the way, I learned that once a service worker is registered, it immediately begins downloading all cached resources. I had assumed that resources were cached only after the page loaded them. I also found some definitive event patterns to indicate which lifecycle phase was occurring.

For a new install, the following events are logged in the above script:

```
window.onload -> reg.updatefound -> sw.ready -> nw.activated
```

For this case, when `sw.ready` fires, all resources have been cached. At this point, I can switch the app from the 'please wait' phase and dynamically load the cached resources and start the app.

For a simple page refresh, the following events are logged:

```
window.onload -> sw.ready
```

This will be the event sequence if the app has already been downloaded and no updates are available. At this point, I can again switch phase and start the app.

For a page refresh when the service worker script has been updated, the following events are logged:

```
window.onload -> sw.ready -> reg.updatefound -> nw.activated
```

In this case, when `nw.activated` fires, all cached resources have been updated. Another page refresh is required to actually load the changes. At this point, the user could be prompted to update. Or the app would update on its own the next time it was started.

By tracking these event patterns, it is easy to tell which lifecycle phase the service worker is in and take the appropriate action.